# All firefox add-ons got disabled and can't download any from Mozilla web page

Tags: windows, firefox, windows-8.1, firefox-extensions

I have a notebook with Windows 8.1 and Firefox 66.0.3; all the add-ons got suddenly disabled.
So I uninstalled them and tried to reinstall them from Mozilla web page but I get a red label that says something about a download failed, check your connection.

Also tried by deleting the user profile with same results.

What can be wrong?

Comment: This seems to likely be an certificate issue on Mozilla's side.

Comment: @Anaksunaman But why only in my notebook? Now I'm from my PC(W7 x64) and work fine. Also why don't download them?

Comment: Offhand, I don't know why only your notebook browser might have this issue. But the [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1548973) seems to indicate that downloads are apparently affected as well -- "Firefox marked addons due signing as unsupported, but doesn't allow re-downloads from AMO → All extensions disabled due to expiration of intermediate signing cert".

Comment: My understanding is that Firefox blocks addons with "issues".